# where does pg_dumpall store *.bak file?

Tags: postgresql

I want to dump a database. and I use:

```
pg_dumpall
```

by using this code, data which has been stored on data base is scrolling in the terminal and it says:

`PostgreSQL database dump complete`

`PostgreSQL database cluster dump complete`

but I can not find any new .bak file any where. I also used:

```
pg_dumpall -f test
```

it goes to next line without showing any message.

finally, where is stored .bak file?!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.bak` file until you name it so.

With the last command in your question, the dump is written to the file `test` — this, then, is your “`.bak` file”.

In fact, it is an SQL script, because `pg_dumpall` only supports the plain text format.

You restore such a dump by feeding it to `psql`:

```
psql -h hostname -p 1234 -f test -d postgres -U postgres
```

Where “1234” is the port number of your new database cluster.

Answer (score 0):

By default, pg_dumpall writes its output to stdout, i.e the terminal. 
There *is* no .bak file, because you didn't ask it to create one.

Either direct the output to a file or, better still, use pg_dumpall's "-f" argument to name the file you want the output written to:

```
pg_dumpall ...  > ./backup.bak 
pg_dumpall ...  -f ./backup.bak
```